# How to keep only digits in a cell in OpenRefine using GREL

Tags: openrefine, grel

For example, the cell contains

```
5.6
4
5years
6years
```

How can I make it so it will only keep the digits?

Expected output:

```
5.6
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use [regular expressions](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/expressions#regular-expressions) for this task.

So for example use the [transformation dialog](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/cellediting#transform) via "Edit cells" => "Transform..." and the GREL Expression:

```
value.find(/\d+(\.\d+)?/).join(" ")
```

This will search for decimal like digits in the text and then concatenate ([join](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#joina-sep)) the resulting list (array) via whitespace.